# SWIFTUI - creating a ForEach with Searchbar, text and button

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am building a list which should have more than 100 elements (in the future) but the alignment seems not to work..

Currently i have this...

[image]

I think it looks pretty nice atm - but the problem is, when you clicked an element (it doesnt matter which one) every element will be clicked... I tested this by print command.
[image]

The searchbar works pretty fine, except from hiding the head - but that is not the problem right now..

When you search for an item, the correct item will be displayed and by clicking on it, the correct command appears...

[image]

I am looking for my mistake, but i cant find it.. Maybe you guys can help me :-)

This is my code...

```
struct RecipeIngredientsView: View {
    let myArray = ["Dennis", "Tessa", "Peter", "Anna", "Tessa", "Klaus", "Xyan", "Zuhau", "Clown", "Brot", "Bauer"]
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var showCancelButton: Bool = false

    
    var body: some View {
            VStack
            {
                HStack
                {
                    HStack
                    {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                        TextField("Suche", text: $searchText, onEditingChanged: { isEditing in self.showCancelButton = true}, onCommit: {
                            print("onCommit")
                        }).foregroundColor(.primary)
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            self.searchText = searchText
                            }){
                            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill").opacity(searchText == "" ? 0 : 1)
                            }
                        }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 6, bottom: 8, trailing: 6))
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                        .cornerRadius(10.0)
                        
                        if showCancelButton {
                        Button("Abbrechen")
                            {
                            UIApplication.shared.endEditing(_force: true)
                            self.searchText = ""
                            self.showCancelButton = false
                            }
                                .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBlue))
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .navigationBarHidden(showCancelButton)
                        
                List {
                    VStack{
                        ForEach(myArray.filter{$0.hasPrefix(searchText) || searchText == ""}, id:\.self)
                            {
                            searchText in VStack {
                            CardView(searchText: searchText)
                            }
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Suche"))
                .resignKeyboardOnDragGesture()
            }
        }
    }

struct CardView : View
{
    @State var searchText = ""
    var body : some View
    {
        HStack{
            Text(searchText)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {print("\(searchText) btn pressed!")})
                {
                Image(systemName: "circle")
                .frame(width:25, height:25)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                }
             }
    }
}
```

Thank you guys & merry x-mas!:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because of :

```
List {
 VStack{
  //.... ForEach loop
 }
}
```

Like that the list contains just one element , which is the `VStack`

To avoid this your code should be like that :

```
List {
 ForEach(myArray.filter{$0.hasPrefix(searchText) || searchText == ""}, id:\.self)
   { searchText in
      CardView(searchText: searchText)
    }
 }
```